Swagger-ui в nginx
Каким способом можно реализовать swagger-ui в nginx в случае когда он выполняет роль gateway в микросервисах?
Читал в официальной документации, что такая поддержка из коробки существует только в платной версии nginx plus. Также сам понимаю, что можно вручную создать файлик свагера и смаппить с каким нибудь адресом. Однако при таком варианте нельзя отослать тестовые запросы. Есть ли способы сделать это в бесплатной версии?
